# May I know how to make the icon position in the same line with the text?

Tags: flutter

[image: Positioning the icon same line with the text]

```
      title: const Text("Test", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
          actions: [
            Column(children: <Widget>[
              Align(alignment: Alignment.topLeft),
              Image.asset(
                'Assets/Images/calendar.png',
              ),
              Text(formattedDate, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))
            ]),
```

To position the icon same line with text

Comment: Use ROW instead of Column. Column are used to place widget vertically and Row for Horizontally.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Row` widget.

```dart
      title: const Text("Test", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
          actions: [
            Row(
             mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
             children: <Widget>[
             // Align(alignment: Alignment.topLeft),
              Image.asset(
                'Assets/Images/calendar.png',
              ),
              Text(formattedDate, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))
            ]),
```

More about [layout in flutter](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/layout)

Answer (score 0):

This may work !!

```
title: const Text("Test", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
              actions: const [
                Center(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                    child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          // Align(alignment: Alignment.topLeft),
                          Icon(Icons.calendar_month),
                          Text("formattedDate",
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))
                        ]),
                  ),
                ),
              ]
```